# Push values into an array and refresh that array when another selection is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have three select lists that are filled with table names, column names and attribute names. I push them to a variable like this:

```
data.forEach(function(field){
            fieldList.push(field);
```

But if I change a select list it adds all the column names of the second table to the array like this:
[Here u you can find an exmample of what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beEdK.png)

Comment: please add the wanted parts of the image as text into the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want data of the last selected table, clear array on your event.

```
fieldList = [];
data.forEach(function(field){
            fieldList.push(field);
}
```

Comment: You'r suggestion doesn't fix the problem. Still haveing the same problem.

Comment: It does exactly as you write in your image, clearing the array before adding the fields

Comment: You have to add more code or a better description then.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Just needed to add this line infront of the code:
  `fieldList.length = 0;` . This line empty's the array before it gets filled again.